# How can I update the content of Facebook comments during AJAX-navigation

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to put a Facebook Comments box on a page where the navigation is AJAX based. How can I trigger the Facebook Comments box to reflect the new AJAX loaded page?

Example:
User visits example.com?page=1, load comments for example.com?page=1.
User clicks a link which updates the page to reflect the content of page=2, load comments for page=2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the click handler for loading ajax pages, you can replace the facebook comments code with the code for the new pages

```
<fb:comments href="example.com" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

Replace example.com with the URL of the page fetched. Also, this goes in the header:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=188677664483920&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
```

Another thing: You will need to instruct the facebook API to parse all the xfbml tags again in the click handler after adding the new code by calling `FB.XFBML.parse();`

If this is not clear enough, let me know and I will post a complete example code.

Comment: It was FB.XFBML.parse() I was looking for. Tnx. Made a hack using Init, put parse is probably a lot better.

Comment: I've noticed the span "Posting as John Doe" is scrunched up when using FB.XFBML.parse() in this way. That span is in a div which, for some reason, has width: 0. Any ideas what's going on there? Can't seem to override it with CSS since it's in an iframe.

Comment: @chris: Hmm. weird. I haven't actually used fb:comments with FB.XFBML.parse(), only a few other tags like fb:login, fb:registration, fb:like-box.. If its only that particular div, it could be a bug on fb's end. Try clearing your cache and checking, as it might have been fixed in a newer version, maybe?

Comment: I'm thinking it must be a bug. Some friends have visited the page and confirmed it. If the external CSS feature was still working, I could fix it. Alas, apparently it was removed in this latest version. Oh well!